# plot histogram matplotlib with labels on x axis instead of count

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm looking to plot a histogram using `value_counts()` or some equivalent, in python. My data looks like:

```
Lannister                      8
Stark                          8
Greyjoy                        7
Baratheon                      6
Frey                           2
Bolton                         2
Bracken                        1
Brave Companions               1
Darry                          1
Brotherhood without Banners    1
Free folk                      1
Name: attacker_1, dtype: int64
```

You could use any reproducible code like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Family':['Lannister', 'Stark'], 'Battles':[6, 8]})
```

I'm using

```
plt.hist(battles.attacker_1.value_counts())
```

[image: histogram]

I would like the x axis to show the family names, instead of the number of battles, and I would like the number of battles to be the histogram piece. I tried using just a series of the family names (with Lannister repeating 8 times) instead of using `value_counts()` and thought that might work, but I'm not sure how else to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
battles.attacker_1.value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Comment: opps... seems like you find your answer :-)

Comment: I did actually do some research, It just took me a bit haha. Thank you for the post!

Comment: `import seaborn as sns;
sns.countplot(x='Family', data=battles)`

Answer (score 3):

For a **vanilla matplotlib** solution, use `xticklabels` with `xticks`:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


NUM_FAMILIES = 10

# set the random seed (for reproducibility)
random.seed(42)

# setup the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# generate some random data
x = [random.randint(0, 5) for x in range(NUM_FAMILIES)]

# create the histogram
ax.hist(x, align='left') # `align='left'` is used to center the labels

# now, define the ticks (i.e. locations where the labels will be plotted)
xticks = [i for i in range(NUM_FAMILIES)]

# also define the labels we'll use (note this MUST have the same size as `xticks`!)
xtick_labels = ['Family-%d' % (f+1) for f in range(NUM_FAMILIES)]

# add the ticks and labels to the plot
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xtick_labels)

plt.show()
```

Which yields:

[image: histogram plot]

Answer (score 1):

You may look at `pandas` `plot`

```
df.set_index('Family').Battles.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]